# Change background color of tabBar in v4 viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, tablet, styling

I'm building an app for Android using a viewPager, and things work just fine on a phone, but on a tablet there is a gray background on both sides of the tabs, the need is to change this background color to white.

[On a phone it Looks just fine, sorry for ugly censoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECN65.png)

[On a tablet the gray background appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbk83.png)

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```

The styles I've tried to override are the ones below, I've tried to set most properties that contain the word "color" to white, but nothing has worked.

- `android:actionBarStyle`
- `android:actionBarTabStyle`
- `android:actionBarTabBarStyle`

I base my theme on `Theme.AppCompat.Light`

I've also tried setting the background of the viewPager and actionBar in code, but it did nothing, I'm guessing it's a subview I need to get to. I've been googling my heart out but I can't find anything about this specific styling.

Comment: is that your parent Layout?

Comment: It's the entire layout, yep.

Comment: I saw the edit suggestions, and I'm sorry I can't post inline images due to not having enough reputation. I use SO a whole lot, but mostly reading, this is my second question ever :P

Funny is that if I edit the post my links were converted to inline images, and then I couldn't save due to again my reputation being too low, hah.

Comment: Not an issue dude :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"  />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ah, I got hopeful, but a layout beneath the viewpager did no difference. It could have been transparency but apparently not :(